# How to trigger TreeView LostFocus event

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView like this:

```
        <TreeView LostFocus="treeView_LostFocus">
            <TreeViewItem Selected="treeViewItem_select"/>
        </TreeView>
```

it always trigger event `treeView_LostFocus` first when I select different item in TreeViewItem using `treeViewItem_select`. How can I do to trigger the lost focus event only when the the `TreeView` losing focus, not before trigger `treeViewItem_select`?

ps: make `e.Handle = true` in the end of `treeViewItem_select` seems not work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to check if the KeyboardFocus is still within the TreeView.

```
private void treeView_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tv = sender as TreeView;

    if (tv.IsKeyboardFocusWithin == false)
    {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

That way when your child items get focus, your code won't get executed. Only when the whole TreeView loses focus.

Comment: It works. But still have an another problem. I should make the selected treeviewitem as unselected when the whole TreeView lost focus so that I can trigger the select event agagin when I reselect the same treeviewitem. So I just put the code `treeViewItem.IsSelected = false`(treeViewItem is the name of TreeViewItem in xaml), it seems not work. am I wrong in somewhere?

Comment: Maybe MouseDoubleClick event is a good choice. Somehow I have to put it into Selected event.

Comment: @Dragon I think with a MouseDown event or another MouseClick event on the TreeViewItems where you reselect your item or just run the code you want to, probably solves your problem. But that's an entirely different question. If you still have problems getting this to work, I suggest you create another question where you describe your problem more completely and exactly what you're trying to achieve.